# Accessing Sitecore API from a Web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, sitecore

I am wondering how to get to the Sitecore content through the Sitecore API in a separate webservice, I tried SiteContextSwitcher but I get a "Cannot load provider" Exception. 
Should I somehow register this webservice in sitecore to use it ?

EDIT: 
I would like to expose over WebService functions to publish specific items (by GUID or path)

Comment: Could you please explain in more details what would you like to achieve? Why is @sitecore-climber's answer not what you need? Which functionality of Sitecore you would like to expose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add web service to your website where you will have access to the Sitecore API and expose functions you need eg. publishing a page

You will need an ASMX service which you can call by URL to the file ie. `http://server.com/Some/Directory/Service.asmx/YourMethodName`

Since it's called in the context of the Sitecore application you will have access to the API in the service. You can pass the path to the item or the id using parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sitecore Web APi module to get Sitecore Content .
[Here](http://goo.gl/q2nYeU)  you can find it. 
I think you don't need your own WebService, with this module you can get Sitecore content out of the box. It's really easy to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not what I was thinking about, I need to expose some funcionality of Sitecore over WebService.